# Create python project in eclipse with Pydev fails, why?

Tags: python

> Error: The selected wizard could not be started.

`Plug-in org.python.pydev was unable to load class org.python.pydev.ui.wizards.project.PythonProjectWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.python.pydev (547).`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs as a result of installing the wrong version of PyDev for the version of Eclipse that you're using (found a hint on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554383/pydev-on-eclipse-portable-pydev-refuses-to-work)).

For example, I (***Edit**: used to*) use Eclipse Luna (Service Release 2, v4.4.2). I tend to lose my plugins / settings every time I update Eclipse on a Mac, and I'm too lazy to look into why, so I've avoided updating. Which is how I ran into the problem you describe here.

The version of PyDev [available in the Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse) is, as of this writing, 6.5.something. You'd think Eclipse would be smart enough not to allow incompatible plugins to be installed with the Marketplace installer, but nope.

Look [here](http://www.pydev.org/download.html) for an idea of which version of PyDev you need to work with your version of Eclipse (check the "About" box within Eclipse), then follow the instructions [here](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) to download the appropriate .zip [from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/), extract it, and move the extracted files into the `dropins` directory, preserving the hierarchy that existing inside the archive.

For Eclipse Luna (4.4), I found that [PyDev 5.2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/PyDev%205.2.0/) seems to work fine (so far).

Note that the location of the `dropins` folder may vary by operating system. Once upon a time, I bookmarked [this reference](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html) (for Luna) from the Eclipse help, and it may be useful somehow.